# Multiprocessing file reading and output

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to process files in over 1000 directories. However, as the size of the directory is very big, i have to run the process concurrently to save time. The dir [:100] is so that that function has only 100 directories to process.However, the 2nd Thread does not start until the first Thread has finished.

```
def sort(start,end):
 dir = os.list(filepath)
 dir = dir [start:end]
 for file in dir:
  ~process~
  print result 

if __name__ == '__main__':
 Thread(target = Sort(0,100)).start()
 Thread(target = Sort(100,200)).start()
```

I have tried duplicating the Sort function as Sort2(): but this yields the same result

```
Thread(target = Sort(0,100)).start()
Thread(target = Sort2(100,200)).start()
```

Any help or direction is greatly apprenticed

Comment: possible duplicate of [python threading blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946075/python-threading-blocks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Sort` and `Sort2` are being evaluated before you start your threads. When you say `Sort(...)`, the `()` is an operator that executes the `Sort` function.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946075/python-threading-blocks) could say more about your problem.

You'll have to use the `args` parameter for the `Thread` constructor. For example:

```
Thread(target=Sort, args=(0,100)).start()
```

Comment: Thank you! I didnt know this before

Answer (score 1):

```
import multiprocessing

def worker_sort():
    # includes the code of your sorting function
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(2):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_sort, args=(0,100))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

I'd recommend some reading about the multiprocessing module in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)