# Why doesn't the code is executing after thread start right away? Isn't it supposed to be non-blocking?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous

Hi guys I don't get it why my code is getting stucked in the line where I am starting my thread. In this thread, I am willing to run these two asynchronous task but as soon as i am starting the thread as target (t3.start()), its getting block and followed up lines are not getting executed. After t3.start() line, print statement in the line is never getting executed. P.S. My Asynchronous task is working fine.

'''

```
import threading 
import os
from time import sleep
import asyncio
async def asynctask1():
    print("Task 1 assigned to thread: {}".format(threading.current_thread().name))
    print("ID of process running task 1: {}".format(os.getpid()))
    while True:
        print("I am async task 1")
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
async def asynctask2():
    print("Task 2 assigned to thread: {}".format(threading.current_thread().name))
    print("ID of process running task 2: {}".format(os.getpid()))
    while True:
        print("Hi I am async task 2")
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
async def main ():
    asyncTask1 = asyncio.create_task(asynctask1())
    asyncTask2 = asyncio.create_task(asynctask2())
    await asyncTask1
    await asyncTask2
print("ID of process running main program: {}".format(os.getpid()))
print("Main thread name: {}".format(threading.current_thread().name))
t3 = threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run(main()), name='t3')
t3.start()
#Here its getting stucked and following print statement is not getting executed
print("==================Printing after thread task started============================")
```

'''

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python threading blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946075/python-threading-blocks)

Comment: 'threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run(), name='t3')' I dont get it, how am i supposed to invoke the main async function without giving parenthesis and past it as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> I dont get it, how am i supposed to invoke the main async function without giving parenthesis and past it as parameter.

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do, so I won't try to actually answer your question, but do you understand what this statement does?

```
t3 = threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run(main()), name='t3')
```

That statement will

- call `main()`, and then after main() returns it will
- call `asyncio.run(`r`)` where *r* is whatever value was returned by main(), and then after run(...) returns it will
- create a new `Thread` instance with `target=`*t*, where *t* is whatever was returned by the asyncio.run(...) call.

If you want to talk about a *function*, (e.g., to pass a function as the `target` of a thread) then just write the name of the function.  Any time you put parentheses after the name of a function, that *calls* the function.

Comment: I want to create two asynchronous task under a Thread. As I have stated my code above, after I am starting my thread in the line t3.start(), its getting stucked, I mean asynchrnous task is working fine but the next line is not getting executed. Last Print line is not getting executed. Thats my problem.

Comment: 'print("====Printing after thread task started====") #This line is never getting executed'

Comment: I doubt that `t3.start()` ever gets called. I've never used `asyncio`, and I can't tell you how to use it.  I'm _guessing_ that either `main()` never returns or `asyncio.run(...)` never returns. I'm _guessing_ that you want to pass `asyncio.run` (i.e., just use the _name_ of the function, don't try to _call_ it) as the `target` of the thread. But, I don't know what `args=...` it's going to want. You'll have to wait for some more knowledgeable person to answer that.